# Cоздать функцию цифрового корня

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function digital_root(n) {
  var arrString = String(n).split("");
  console.log(arrString);
  var sum = 0;
  for(var s=0; s<arrString.length; s++){
    sum += +arrString[s];
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
```

Допустим n=16

```
//digital_root(16) (1+6) -> 7.
```

Но что делать если n больше чем 2 знака:

n=456 -> (4+5+6)=15 -> (1+5)=6;

Суть вопроса: как мне переделать код выше, чтобы он мог найти решение с n>2 знаков. Сделать это через цикл или как?

Comment: Использовать цикл типа `while` и выполнять суммирование в нем до тех пор, пока результат не станет 1 знаком.

Comment: Какой в баню цикл??? поделить на 9 и взять остаток (остаток 0 == сумма 9, если само число не ноль)... признаки делимости - школа, блин, класс пятый.

Comment: я немного не понял, что у вас в коде не так? у вас `var arrString = String(n).split("");` разбивает n на символы. Даже если это 456 вы получите `"4", "5", "6"`

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, проблема автора в том, что сейчас для `456` он получит `4+5+6` -> `15`. А должен получить - 6

Comment: вопросов больше нет )

Answer (score 0):

```js
function digital_root(n) {return (n==0) ? 0 : 1+(n-1)%9;}

console.log("digital_root(16)=" + digital_root(16));
console.log("digital_root(456)=" + digital_root(456));
console.log("digital_root(0)=" + digital_root(0));
```

Comment: очень благодарен за ответ.